# Why is the defaulted constructor not constexpr here?

Tags: c++, constructor, c++17, constexpr

The following example seems to compile with Clang but not with gcc. Which one is right?

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct MyType
{
  constexpr MyType () = default;
  //constexpr MyType () {}

  constexpr bool is_int () const
  {
    return std::is_same_v<T, int>;
  }
};

constexpr auto foo ()
{
  MyType<int> retval;
  //MyType<int> retval {};

  return retval;
}

int main ()
{
  static_assert (foo ().is_int ());
}
```

Also, note that un-commenting any of the two commented lines (and removing the respective line above it) makes the program compile with gcc, too.

If gcc is right here, why doesn't it compile?

Comment: What does GCC say?

Comment: @liliscent - What do you mean? There's a bunch of errors displayed in red in the console.

Comment: @StoryTeller Not for me.

Comment: @melpomene - Strange. When I opened the link, I got a cascade of red errors (and the compiler was GCC 7.2). When I switched to GCC 8.0.1 it worked. What is the compiler the link opens with for you?

Comment: Anyway, the difference in behavior between 7.2 and 8.0.1 strongly indicates to me this is a bug that has been uncovered and fixed already.

Comment: @StoryTeller GCC HEAD 8.0.1 here.

Comment: @melpomene - I see. So it seems wandbox uses a weird combo of linked code and cookies to break itself. Thanks for confirming it!

Comment: Seems to be [this bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83921).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [complaint](https://godbolt.org/g/pfdAeP) is that you're using an uninitialized variable in a constexpr function. However - that's not the case, i.e. `retval` is default-initialized. So GCC is wrong, unless the standard has very weird language (which I doubt, but don't know for sure).

@StoryTeller suggests this is related to [this bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83921).

Comment: There was at least one standard defect adjacent to that that was forcing me to write code like `struct Foo { constexpr Foo() {}; }` and not `struct Foo { constexpr Foo()=default; }` or even `struct Foo {};`.  I don't know if it applies here, but it was definitely fixed way prior to C++17.

Comment: @Yakk: So you're saying that it was a problem with the _standard_ rather than with GCC as a compiler?

Comment: I am saying way back in C++11 there was a problem in the standard adjacent to this code, and that at some point prior to C++17 it was fixed, I believe as a defect.  The problem in the standard was why I had to write explicit empty constexpr zero arg ctors.  I do not recall the exact defect, when it was fixed, nor if it would apply to the OP's situation; I am just ststing that faith in the standard here should be double checked.

Answer (score 0):

This was [core issue 253 "Why must empty or fully-initialized `const` objects be initialized?"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#253). It was resolved by [P0490R0: "Core language changes addressing National Body comments for CD C++17"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0490r0.html) (scroll down to the "RU 1" heading at the end) just in time for C++17. The change was further applied as a "defect report" against C++14.

You'll see implementation variance between "new" compilers that have implemented this C++17 fix (in both 17 and 14 modes) and "old" compilers that have not.